# Show the download button only if file is available on server in Django template (html)

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using the following template code to show the **Download** option on the webpage.

```
<a href="{%static 'media/finance'%}/sap-daily.csv" download >Download</a>
```

But I want to only show the Download option if the file is present on the server and otherwise show **not available** option.

I am using python 2.7 and django 1.6.7 .

Comment: please post the whole template code only then we can help you, providing a raw link is not that helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is check if the file exists in your views.py with

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("/path/to/file")
if my_file.is_file():
    show_link = True
```

Then in your template HTML:

```
{% if show_link %}
  <a href="{%static 'media/finance'%}/sap-daily.csv" download >Download</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is it possible to write the whole thing in template (html file)?

Comment: It might be, but why should you? It's much easier to handle this in your views.py.